# Django Rest Framework object with relationship

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How do I find an object with relationship and how to save an object in relationship with Django Rest Framework?

I looked in the documentation and found something similar to this

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile')



class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('nome_empresa', 'cnpj')
```

profile = ProfileSerializer()
NameError: name 'ProfileSerializer' is not defined

Comment: you have valid data and mow you need to write relation?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to go through.

Comment: def get(self, request, format=None):
        user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        user_data = UserSerializer(user)

        return Response(user_data.data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is not a compiled language. Everything is created/done at runtime.

At the following line:

```
profile = ProfileSerializer()
```

you are using the `ProfileSerializer` but at this point it is not created yet. It is created a little later. To fix this, you need to put it before the `UserSerializer` class:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('nome_empresa', 'cnpj')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile')
```

Hope it helps!